# Close navigation when scrolled or clicking outside the menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want To close the menu toggle when clicked outside the menu and also close the previous drop down menu while clicking new drop down:

```js
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('nav ul li a:not(:only-child)').click(function(e) {
      $(this).siblings('.nav-dropdown').toggle();
      $('.dropdown').not($(this).siblings()).hide();
      e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('html').click(function() {
      $('.nav-dropdown').hide();
    });
    $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
      $('nav ul').slideToggle();
    });
    $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
      this.classList.toggle('active');
    });
    $('#nav-toggle').on('click', function() {
      document.getElementById("mk").style.fontSize = "2.0em";

    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.nav-bar {
  height: 70px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.brand {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.brand a img {
  max-height: 70px;
}

.brand a,
.brand a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-container {
  max-width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:visited:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after,
nav ul li a:visited:not(:only-child):after {
  padding-left: 4px;
  content: ' ▾';
}

nav ul li ul li {
  min-width: 190px;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.nav-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.nav-mobile {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #262626;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1164px) {
  .nav-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 70px 0 15px;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul li {
    float: none;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 25%;
  }
  nav ul li ul li a {
    padding-left: 30%;
  }
  .nav-dropdown {
    position: static;
  }
  .brand a img {
    max-height: 60px;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1165px) {
  .nav-list {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

#nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
}

#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before,
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

article {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="nav-bar" id="mk">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="nav-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a></div>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="courses">Courses</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#">HTML</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">CSS</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="students.html">Students</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Photoshop</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Illustrator</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">InDesign</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="career.html">Career</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="opportunity.html">Opportunity</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="media.html">Media</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="html">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Did you even read that first link?

Comment: This is the link for the file where the html and css javascript code is there. i am getting error while pasting the code. Kindly help

Comment: I have given the link of the file

Comment: Please post the code in the question itself so it could be helpful for other users with similar issues in future

Comment: Brother its showing error while pasting the code. specify your code error is coming

Comment: I'm not sure what was the reason for this error, but it should only be the relevant part of the issue - In the editor you have a button with an icon similar to `<>` that allow you to create a working snippet that demonstrate the issue with your code

Comment: @mukeshbehwal I added the code to your answer, hope it will be open soon

Comment: Thanks @alon-eitan for adding the code.

Answer (score 0):

I added a 'dropdown' class on 'a' tag which contains dropdown menus. Here is my code

HTML

```
<section class="nav-bar" id="mk">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-mobile"><a id="nav-toggle" href="#!"><span></span></a></div>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="about.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="courses" class="dropdown">Courses</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#">HTML</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">CSS</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">JavaScript</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="students.html" class="dropdown">Students</a>
          <ul class="nav-dropdown">
            <li>
              <a href="#">Photoshop</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Illustrator</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">InDesign</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="career.html">Career</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="opportunity.html">Opportunity</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="media.html">Media</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="html">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.nav-bar {
  height: 70px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.brand {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.brand a img {
  max-height: 70px;
}

.brand a,
.brand a:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-container {
  max-width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a,
nav ul li a:visited {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 70px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:visited:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

nav ul li a:not(:only-child):after,
nav ul li a:visited:not(:only-child):after {
  padding-left: 4px;
  content: ' ▾';
}

nav ul li ul li {
  min-width: 190px;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.nav-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.nav-mobile {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #262626;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1164px) {
  .nav-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  nav {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 70px 0 15px;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul li {
    float: none;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding-left: 25%;
  }
  nav ul li ul li a {
    padding-left: 30%;
  }
  .nav-dropdown {
    position: static;
  }
  .brand a img {
    max-height: 60px;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1165px) {
  .nav-list {
    display: block !important;
  }
}

#nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 18px;
  top: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
}

#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before,
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

article {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
                 {
  $(".nav-list > li > a").on("click",function(e)
                        {
    $(".nav-dropdown").hide(); // to hide other open dropdown
    e.stopPropagation();
    if($(this).hasClass("dropdown")) //check whether dropdown exists
      {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
        $($($(this).parent()).find(".nav-dropdown")).slideToggle(200); //open current dropdown

  })

  //close dropdown by clicking outside the dropdowm
  $(document).click(function(e){
            var nav_dropdown=document.getElementsByClassName("nav-dropdown");
            let target=e.target;
            if(target === nav_dropdown)
                {
                     $(".nav-dropdown").show();
                }
            else{
                   $(".nav-dropdown").hide();
            }

});


})
```

Comment: The Script is not opening the toggle

Comment: @mukeshbehwal I removed all your jquery code. You can add your toggle opening code with my code and it will work.

Comment: brother the menu is not closing while clicking outside the menu

Comment: Here is a working example of the same code.https://codepen.io/pranaysharma995/pen/jOPBaPV

Comment: Brother the toggle is not opening

Comment: i have added your javascript code. the previous menus is closing but the Menu toggle is not closing while clicking or scrolling outside the menu

Comment: Toggle is working. Please check. I only work on the dropdown menu closing issue. You can take inspiration from this code and try to implement the same behaviors in your mobile toggle.

Comment: Bro can u help me to do the same in mobile toggle also?

Comment: The menu toggle must be closed while clicking or scrolling outside the menu

Comment: @mukeshbehwal , please check the codepen link, I updated the code to hide the dropdown menu on the scroll.